# Select max count per second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE news
(
Id         INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
Headline   VARCHAR (255) NULL,
InDateTime   DATETIME NULL
)
```

How to get records count in per second(InDateTime)?

I'm using `Mysql`

---

Sample records:

```
578921,   'headline1', '8/20/2012 12:01:53 PM' 
578922,   'headline2', '8/20/2012 12:01:53 PM' 
578923,   'headline3', '8/20/2012 12:01:53 PM' 
578924,   'headline4', '8/20/2012 12:01:59 PM' 
578925,   'headline5', '8/20/2012 12:01:59 PM' 
578926,   'headline6', '8/20/2012 12:01:59 PM' 
578927,   'headline7', '8/20/2012 12:01:59 PM' 
578928,   'headline8', '8/20/2012 12:02:03 PM'
```

Expected output:

```
time,                    count
'8/20/2012 12:01:53 PM', 3
'8/20/2012 12:01:59 PM', 4
'8/20/2012 12:02:03 PM', 1
```

Comment: can you include sample records and expected output?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "max count"? I assume you need "count per second".

Comment: Do you mean SELECT count(\*) FROM `news` GROUP BY `InDateTime`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have your tired this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), InDateTime
FROM news
GROUP BY InDateTime
```

Comment: I was writing the same (so +1), but you could also skip the unix_timestamp conversion in the GROUP BY since its a datetime column...

Answer (score 2):

Here you want to group your result according to the `time`.
For every `time` you want the number of rows.
So you can use this query.

```
select time, count(*)
from news
group by time
```

Here `group by time` will create separate group of distinct `time` values.
`select time` will select the time in the first column.
And `count(*)` will give the count of the number of rows containing that value.

Its better you read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Have I given the wrong answer? Or the explanation at my link is wrong?

Comment: No. Your answer is correct. I also upvoted it. Did you read that link. *W3Schools frequently publishes inaccurate or misleading content*. Look at [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104898/187824)

Comment: Ya! I've read both the links. I'll also link to their page one after making sure its correct.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way with any conversion

```
SELECT `time`, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP by `time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT InDateTime AS Time, COUNT(InDateTime) AS Count
FROM NEWS
GROUP BY InDateTime
```

**Result**

```
Time                     Count
2012-08-20 12:01:53.000   3
2012-08-20 12:01:59.000   4
2012-08-20 12:02:03.000   1
```